# DbxRequestConfig is deprecated in API V2?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

project Details:

> version = android studio 3.0 dropbox api v2 = dropbox-core-sdk-2.0.6
>   and dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.5 (I tried both). compileSdkVersion =  26
>   buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("MyApp/1.0", "en_US");
```

Image shows the deprecated call of DbxRequestConfig

[image]

It is in the Dropbox jar file.

[image]

Comment: The API is deprecated, meaning it's old. Use the new version which you can easily find by browsing the javadocs

Comment: But this api is listed in newer version of dropbox.

Comment: Deprecated != removed. There are Android API's that have been deprecated for multiple releases, they don't remove deprecated API's instantly

Comment: Thank you, Zoe issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation, [the `DbxRequestConfig(String clientIdentifier, String userLocale)` constructor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxRequestConfig.html#DbxRequestConfig-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) is deprecated, in favor of using [`DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxRequestConfig.html#newBuilder-java.lang.String-).

There's [an example of using it here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/395d463840778b4c6ec730aef82b0a9dbee10f8e/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/DropboxClientFactory.java#L17).